# Need to disable integrated video card

Tags: graphics-card, integrated-graphics

I have an emachine T3256 and it has a GeForce 4 MX integrated graphics card.

My monitor stopped working, so I tried a backup which also did not turn on. I then realized it was the video card that had stopped working and I was told that I needed to disable the integrated video card.

I looked online for the instructions on how to do this, but everything I read requires a monitor in order to get to the system to disable it. So how would I do this if I can't get a monitor to work.

Answer (score 2):

Without a monitor there isn't a whole lot you can do... Also, if you don't have a dedicated graphics card, disabling your integrated card won't allow you to display anything either.

If you have a GeForce4 mx, this would be a dedicated graphics card. You should see two different spots on the back of your PC where you can plug in a monitor cable. One is the motherboard (onboard, or integrated graphics), and one is the discrete graphics card (your GeForce card).

If the cable is connected to the geforce card, you'll want to unplug the monitor, open up the case, remove the video card, and plug the monitor back in to your motherboard (should be near the top of the back side of the case). This should allow you to revert back to the integrated graphics.

If your video card is bad, you'll need to get another video card if the integrated graphics aren't enough for you. Otherwise, your computer should work just fine from now on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am still confused. The GeForce is the integrated card. There is only one spot to plug in the monitor. It seems to be in the spot that you mention. Towards the top of the back side.  This is the info I have concerning the video card:

Comment: Look at the answer @Josh gave, this explains it much better than I can.

Answer (score 2):

I read a [review](http://reviews.cnet.com/desktops/emachines-t3256/4505-3118_7-31154277.html) that said "two free PCI slots and an AGP slot for upgrading the integrated graphics with a third-party card".

So if it's the card, at least there is that option.

As far as getting the computer configured to use a new graphics card, I think you're going to have to get remote access to the computer.  That is, you're going to need another computer to remotely control the emachines computer.

This is more difficult of course without the ability to configure the emachine for remote access.

One tool that may help is [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).  I'm not knowledgeable enough to be able to walk you through it, but you may be able to tailor a new question to get help using it.

Another line of attack could be something like ["How to remotely enable remote desktop"](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-remotely-enable-remote-desktop-terminal-services-or-rdp-via-registry-in-windows-2000xp2000vista2008/).  This certainly isn't the only tutorial out there about this, but it may also just get you on the right track, asking the right questions.

Comment: I've never heard of third party cards improving integrated graphics... This is an interesting concept. I assume its outdated now since integrated graphics are so much better now (especially with ivy bridge), but still, it's a good idea to pay less for more.

Comment: On the contrary, actually, 3rd party cards are capable of significant improvements over integrated varieties.  Of course not all aftermarket cards are muscle-bound, but if you're looking for muscle, you're looking at aftermarket cards.

Comment: Sorry my comment must have been confusing... I thought your answer meant the graphics card was there to boost the integrated graphics card and not provide its own (dedicated) graphics. I have a 7970 of my own, so I definitely know the muscle you're talking about ;)